# How to invoke IComparable<T> when executing Array.BinarySearch

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, sorting

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y15ef976.aspx) documenting the behavior of the BinarySearch method shows that both the array and the value being searched may implement IComparable:

1) The page describes

> Either `value` or every element of `array` must implement the `IComparable`
>   interface, which is used for comparisons.

2) Further, the method throws an `InvalidOperationException` if

> `value` does not implement the `IComparable` interface, and the search
>   encounters an element that does not implement the `IComparable`
>   interface.

I was trying to demonstrate this behavior (using the IComparable interface of value) but was unable to. Here is my code:

```
// Declarations
class Many 
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
class One : Many, IComparable<Many>
{
    public int CompareTo(Many other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Comparator of One invoked");
        if (this.data.Length < other.data.Length) return -1;
        if (this.data.Length > other.data.Length) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
...
// action
    Many[] manies = new[] { new Many { data = "1" }, 
                            new Many { data = "22" },  
                            new Many { data = "333" }, 
                            new Many { data = "4444" }, };
    One one = new One {data="333"};
    Console.WriteLine(Array.BinarySearch(manies, one));
```

When I run this I get a `System.InvalidOperationException`, which according to the documentation should occur if `value` does not implement `IComparable`. However it seems to me that it does implement `IComparable`.

How do I get the comparator of value to run, instead of that of the elements in the array?

Comment: You need to inherit IComparable in the Many class, not the One class.  The only meaningful way to compare a base class object to a derived class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I understand the question, change your implementation of `One` to implement `IComparable` and not `IComparable<Many>`.  Looking at the documentation I think that is the missing component.  You can implement both if you need to, but `Array.BinarySearch` will not use the `IComparable<T>` interface.

This code is working for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class NoCompare
    {
        public string V
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Compare : IComparable
    {
        public string V
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            NoCompare a = obj as NoCompare;

            if (a == null)
                return -1;

            return String.Compare(V, a.V);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NoCompare[] strings = new NoCompare[] { new NoCompare() { V = "a" }, new NoCompare() { V = "b" }, new NoCompare() { V = "c" } };

            Compare t = new Compare();
            t.V = "b";

            Array.BinarySearch((object[])strings, t);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer to better address your particular question.