# Can't invoke the comparator of the key in Array.BinarySearch

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

To observe the invocation of the comparator of the key (as opposed to the typical scenario which involves the invocation of the comparator of the array elements) in System.Array.BinarySearch we set up the following test:

```
class Many 
{
    public string data { get; set; }
}
class One : Many, IComparable
{
    public int CompareTo(object arg)
    {
        Many other = arg as Many;
        Console.WriteLine("Comparator of One invoked from: " + this.data);
        if (this.data.Length < other.data.Length) return -1;
        if (this.data.Length > other.data.Length) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

With these new declarations when I run the following:

```
   Many[] manies = new[] { new Many { data = "1" }, 
                           new Many { data = "22" }, 
                           new Many { data = "333" }, 
                           new Many { data = "4444" }, };
   One one = new One {data="???"};
   Console.WriteLine(Array.BinarySearch(manies, one));
```

I get as output:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array. ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectComparer`1.Compare(T x, T y)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.InternalBinarySearch(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.BinarySearch(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.BinarySearch(T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.BinarySearch[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, T value, IComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Array.BinarySearch[T](T[] array, T value)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Prosram.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line xxx
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to invoke IComparable<T> when executing Array.BinarySearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235087/how-to-invoke-icomparablet-when-executing-array-binarysearch)

Comment: @HansPassant the two are related because they concern the comparer of the key, but there are two separate issues. This page discusses an error in the documentation of the BCL, the other one you refer to discusses a "mere" programmer error. I consider this page to be the more useful one, so I would like to avoid it being cluttered with a duplicate tag. Can you please remove your flag and either make a reference from this page, or mark the other page as the possible duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has always been a problem with the behavior of `BinarySearch` in that the comparator of the key was never actually executed, even though the MSDN documentation says that was the case if the array elements did not implement `IComparable`. This problem was solved in version 4.5 of .NET.

There are clues in the stack trace of the error that show the error originating in `System.Collections.Comparer.Compare()`. Looking at the .NET source code of this method in .NET 4.5 and in .NET 4.0 shows an important change to the way this method was implemented:

**.NET 4.5:**

```
public int Compare(Object a, Object b) {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    ...
    IComparable ia = a as IComparable; 
    if (ia != null)
        return ia.CompareTo(b); 

    IComparable ib = b as IComparable;
    if (ib != null) 
        return -ib.CompareTo(a);

    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString(
                                       "Argument_ImplementIComparable"));
```

**.NET 4.0:**

```
public int Compare(Object a, Object b) {
    if (a == b) return 0;
    ...
    IComparable ia = a as IComparable; 
    if (ia != null)
        return ia.CompareTo(b); 

    throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString(
                                      "Argument_ImplementIComparable"));
```

In our case, we want to observe that the comparator of the key is being invoked, and the key in this case is `b` while the element in the array is `a`.

This means that the the documentation on MSDN of the BinarySearch method was incorrect for .NET versions before 4.5. The method does not take the `Comparator` of the key into account if the elements in the array do not implement `IComparable`, because the implementation depends on `Comparer` actually doing that and it does not do that, throwing an `ArgumentException` instead. However, in version 4.5 it does work as always documented in `BinarySearch`.